# How can I route non-local incoming connections on a specific port to my computer's local network adapter rather than a VPN?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, port-forwarding

I have a mac running macOS 10.14, and it's connected to a VPN (using OpenVPN) with the VPN's gateway being the default gateway / route for all outgoing traffic. This has the effect that I cannot connect to any service on my mac from an arbitrary outside IP address, even if I've properly set up port forwarding on my router. (Other systems from the same local network as the mac can connect to its services, though.)

Is there some way I can configure things so that an incoming connection from a non-local IP on a specific port will be routed to my mac's local IP / physical network adapter, rather than through the VPN?

I'm open to solutions that involve changing something about the configuration on my mac, perhaps using static routes or pf, or changing the configuration on my router. For example, if there's some way to configure my router to forward incoming traffic on this port to my mac, but change the source IP of that connection to the router's IP, I think that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there's some way to configure my router to forward incoming traffic on this port to my mac, but change the source IP of that connection to the router's IP, I think that will do the trick.

That's really ugly in my opinion, but yes, it should be easy to do. Source IP translation is done with regular SNAT (masquerading) that the router already uses for all outbound packets, only it needs to be applied to inbound traffic this time.

It depends on your router whether its UI will *let you* configure SNAT for anything else than regular outbound traffic, but anything based on iptables (OpenWRT or RouterOS) or nftables or pf will have the capability.

An answer that implements source-specific routing via macOS `pf` would generally be a better solution.

Alternatively, if the *router* (instead of macOS itself) were the OpenVPN client, then you could apply the existing "Linux policy routing" answers to it.

Comment: "An answer that implements source-specific routing via macOS pf would generally be a better solution." I'm inclined to agree. However, I only know the most basic usage of pf and don't really know where to begin configuring it to treat incoming traffic on a certain port differently than other traffic.

Comment: I managed to get this working using SNAT masquerading as you suggested, but basically using it in reverse for masquerading an incoming connection rather than outgoing. I have a Ubiquiti EdgeRouter and it does let me configure it this way, though I imagine most consumer routers would not.